# How long simple variable lasts?

Tags: flutter, dart

How long variable like **String email** lasts in application?

If I assign something to this variable, can I use it till the restart of application?

Comment: No, it will not keep after restart

Comment: Hi! You question needs to be more specific. Variables can have different lifetime depends on scope. Please add some code sample.

Comment: try [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) use Keychain in IOS and KeyStore in Android

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't worry about such things.

As long as you have a reference to this variable, it won't be collected by the Garbage Collector and you will be able to access it for as long as the application runs (unless you hot restart or stop it).

Answer (score 0):

Variables are stored in memory till application restart, you cannot use it after restart. If you want to reuse variable after restart, consider using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package. It will store this variable behind runtime and you can retrieve them after restarting the application.